# Glissando on ListView/LinearLayout

Tags: android, listview, user-experience

Let's say I have a LinearView or a ListView filled with different but similar views:

```
------------
| View 1   |
------------
| View 2   |
------------
| View 3   |
------------
| View 4   |
------------
```

Each view has it's own OnClickListener to react to user interactions.

I want to be able to react to a user's finger on a glide that spans one or several views and trigger their reactions whenever the user's finger is on top of them, no matter if another View's touch listener was already triggered or if the slide is finished already or not.

If the views were piano keys, I want to be able to play a [Glissando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glissando), sliding my finger on top of the keys and triggering their sounds without lifting the finger from the screen.

How should I apporach this? What kind of listener should I use to handle the user's slide?

Answer (score 0):

Feels like your approach of using a ListView is wrong.  A linear layout is better and on a touch gesture on the LinearLayout you can check for intersections with the views.

But, if the views aren't complex (like a piano) than a better approach will be to write a custom view and draw everything on it's canvas and handle things there

Answer (score 0):

write your custom view this `onTouch` event

```
public class VView extends View implements OnClickListener {
....
public void init(){
this.onTouchListener(this);
}
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
//canvas code...
    }

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            ///your code
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The View in onTouch is the one that the user's vinger is currently sliding on top of?

Comment: I will, let me try it first. Thanks again.